# Problem with Regex for git commit-msg hook

Tags: regex, git, commit

I'm trying to write into git commit-msg hook to check for my format of commit text before commiting it. I want commit to be like "AJ-XX sometext". Where XX are nums then space and just some text. And my code not working and i'm 99% sure that i have wrong regex, can you help me to write the right one.
It looks likt this:

```
export REGEX='(AJ'-'0-90-9 )'
export ERROR_MSG="Commit message format must match regex \"${REGEX}\""
```

It should accept sth like this - "AJ-54 this is commit"

Comment: You need `[0-9]` to match a digit. Something like `export REGEX='AJ-[0-9][0-9] '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following POSIX ERE compliant regex:

```sh
export REGEX='^AJ-[0-9]{2} .*'
```

If your regex flavor is POSIX BRE, you can use

```sh
export REGEX='^AJ-[0-9]\{2\} .*'
```

If you cannot use regex and can only use wildcards / glob patterns, you ca use

```sh
export REGEX='AJ-[0-9][0-9] *'
```